# Python : Conditionally reject chunks of words otherwise match with regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have this current regex to detect pick up address and all variations of such possible for the different types of images I'm working on :

```
(((exporter)[\'s\s\:]{1,4}?(name)?\s?(and)?\s?(address)?)|((ship|remit)[\ \-]?(from)[\:]?)|((pick)[\s\-]?(up)?\s?(location|address)[\'\s\:]{,4}?)|((cargo|truck|container)?\s?pick[\s\-]?up[\s\:\.]?(at)?\:?))
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/XTGb1A/2) in the regex101 website, I'm checking out the possible samples and their corresponding matches. As of now, all the matches are perfect as per I want. I'm using `re.finditer()` along with `re.IGNORECASE`.

Now I have to consider an additioonal case where if `"pick[\s\-]?up"` is in the string and there is `"full"` afterwards, match with it and also if `"pick[\s\-]?up"` is in the string and there is NOT `"full"` afterwards, match with it but if there is `"pick[\s\-]?up"` in the string and there is `"empty"` after, reject it and don't match with the regex. After all we need to reject matching `"pick up"` where `"empty"` is after `"pick up"`. In that case, in the regex101 link, the sample 4 and sample 5 shouldn't be matched, but it's matching right now.

How do I add an conditional part to the last matching group `((cargo|truck|container)?\s?pick[\s\-]?up[\s\:\.]?(at)?\:?)` for this conditional checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a negative lookahead for the word empty following the match against `pick[\s\-]?up`:

```
(?!.*\bempty\b)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XTGb1A/4)